# fullpage.js - Gradient Backgrounds not applying to sections without slides

Tags: css, gradient, fullpage.js

I need help in fixing an issue I am facing while using [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) plugin to create a static HTML page with Gradient Backgrounds.

The issue is when using the Gradient Backgrounds as demonstrated in [Gradient Backgrounds](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/gradientBackgrounds.html) the gradient style gets applied correctly to slides nested under a section, however the sections without any slides shows a white background.

I tried removing custom CSS styles I added and debugging the plugin's Javascript source code but could not find the root cause for the problem being faced.Ultimately I opened an [issue](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/818) in the repository for the same asking help from the plugin author however he has responded that it looks like CSS issue and there is no problem in plugin because the demo page is working.

The code I am having problem with can be found below and also at http://codepen.io/jigneshgohel/pen/vrxuz

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li data-menuanchor="section1"><a href="#section1">Section1</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="section2"><a href="#section2">Section2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="logo">
        <a href="#section0">
            <img width="200" height="40" alt="logo" src="css/imgs/logo.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">Footer</div>

<div id="content">
    <div class="section" id="#section0">
        Section 0 Content
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="#section1">
        <div class="slide" id="slide1">
            Section 1 Slide 1 Content
        </div>
        <div class="slide" id="slide2">
            Section 1 Slide 2 Content
        </div>

        <div class="slide" id="slide3">
            Section 1 Slide 3 Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="#section2">
        Section 2 Content
    </div>

</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.fullpage/2.4.1/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.fullpage/2.4.1/vendors/jquery.easings.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.fullpage/2.4.1/vendors/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#content').fullpage({
        anchors: ['section0', 'section1', 'section2'],
        //sectionsColor: ['#C63D0F', '#1BBC9B', '#7E8F7C'],
        css3: true,
        scrollOverflow: true
    });
</script>
```

**Custom CSS**

```
/* Custom Styles */

#menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    color: #000;
    background:#fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
}
#menu li.active{
    background:#666;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
    color: #fff;
}
#menu li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000;
}
#menu li.active a:hover{
    color: #000;
}
#menu li:hover{
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);
}
#menu li a,
#menu li.active a{
    padding: 2px 18px;
    display:block;
}
#menu li.active a{
    color: #fff;
}
#menu{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 70;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 19px;
    margin:0;
}

/* Centered texts in each section
* --------------------------------------- */
.section{
    text-align:center;
}

/* Fixed header and footer.
* --------------------------------------- */
#header, #footer{
    position:fixed;
    /*height: 50px;*/
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    background: #333;
    z-index:9;
    text-align:center;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}

#header{
    top:0px;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: left;
}
#footer{
    bottom:0px;
    height: 60px;
}

#logo {
    position: relative;
    left: 80%;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 70;
    width: 20%;
}

#logo a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000;
    padding: 2px 18px;
    display:block;
}
#logo a:hover{
    color: #000;
}

#logo a img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

/* Defining each section background and styles
* --------------------------------------- */
#section0{
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, top left, bottom left, from(#4bbfc3), to(#7baabe));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#4BBFC3, #7BAABE);
    background: linear-gradient(#4BBFC3,#7BAABE);
}

#section2 {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, top left, bottom left, from(#969ac6), to(#636F8F));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#969AC6, #636F8F);
    background: linear-gradient(#969AC6,#636F8F);
}

/*Adding background for the slides
* --------------------------------------- */
#slide1{
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, top left, bottom left, from(#7baabe), to(#969ac6));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#7BAABE, #969AC6);
    background: linear-gradient(#7BAABE,#969AC6);
}

#slide2{
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, top left, bottom left, from(#92a1ca), to(#76c2bd));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#92a1ca, #76c2bd);
    background: linear-gradient(#92a1ca,#76c2bd);
}

#slide3{
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, top left, bottom left, from(#92a1ca), to(#76c2bd));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#92a1ca, #76c2bd);
    background: linear-gradient(#92a1ca,#76c2bd);
}
```

I am not good at working with CSS neither fixing any related issues.This can be easily seen seen from my CSS code which I have written by collecting bits and pieces of CSS from plugin's examples and tweaking those as per my needs. Thus requesting help from StackOverflow Community.

Thanks,

Jignesh

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.It was the incorrect DIV id which caused the issue.

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="section" id="#section0">
        Section 0 Content
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="#section1">
        <div class="slide" id="slide1">
            Section 1 Slide 1 Content
        </div>
        <div class="slide" id="slide2">
            Section 1 Slide 2 Content
        </div>

        <div class="slide" id="slide3">
            Section 1 Slide 3 Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="#section2">
        Section 2 Content
    </div>

</div>
```

Instead of *#section0, #section1, #section2* those should have been **section0, section1, section2**.

Thanks,
Jignesh